# Django. Проблема обращения менеджера объектов модели внутри самой модели

Tags: django, model

**Генерируется исключение при обращении к таблице БД изнутри одноимённой модели:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "...\manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "...\Django_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "...\Django_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute django.setup()
File "...\Django_env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "...\Django_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate app_config.import_models()
File "...\Django_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "...\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "...\models.py", line 142, in <module> class EntryType(models.Model):
File "...\models.py", line 148, in EntryType
    ENTRY_TYPES_DICT = get_etypes() 
File "...\models.py", line 145, in get_etypes
            records = EntryType.objects.filter()
        NameError: name 'EntryType' is not defined
        Сборка проекта "Entries 2020.pyproj" завершена с ошибкой.
```

**Описание класса модели:**

```
class EntryType(models.Model):
    ''' Модель типов '''
    def get_etypes():
        records = EntryType.objects.filter()
        return { record.dictKey: (record.shortName, record.fullName) for record in records }

    fullName = models.CharField("Тип заявки", max_length=100, default='')
    shortName = models.CharField("Абревиатура типа", max_length=7, default='')
    dictKey = models.CharField("Ключ идентификации", max_length=7, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Тип заявки: {0}".format(self.fullName)
```

При этом проверены все имена '`EntryType`' на корректность синтаксиса. Кроме того, такой подход  используется и внутри других моделей приложения, например:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    def save():
        ... 
        entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=self.id)
        ...
```

**В чём здеcь может быть проблема??**

Comment: А вы точно в файл эту модель подключили?

Comment: Модель описана в штатном джанговском файле models.py, как и все остальные модели, в частности, приведенная в примере..

Comment: А, увидел сейчас, что в файле был exception... А миграции делали?

Comment: Миграции проведены и отображены в БД. Кроме того, в БД есть даже сама таблица EntryType, с несколькими записями!

Comment: Я не исключаю версию глюка в IDE. Пробовал перезагружать как проект, так и ПК, убирал все комментарии внутри модели, но ситуация не изменилась.

Comment: Я тут не особо вам помогу, ибо обычно не прописываю никакие функции в модели и не патчу стандартные :). Если у вас обращения к модели, например, в файле `views.py` происходят нормально, а тут нет, то, может быть, проблема в этих функциях, но, как я сказал, тут я не силен

Comment: Самое интересное, что модель EntryType - классический дочерний класс Python от базового джанговского класса model. EntryType имеет всего пару методов - метод '__str__' и метод 'get_etypes'. В том числе ничего пропатченного в EntryType нет. EntryType описана классически в стиле Django. Может быть кто-то сталкивался с такой ситуацией?? Версия Django - 3.0.

Comment: Попробуйте в аргумент функции добавить `self` (`get_etypes(self)`), а `EntryType.objects.all()` заменить на `self._meta.model.objects.all()`

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки

Comment: **Эксперименты с добавлением self:** в описание `get_etypes(self)` добавлена строка `records = self._meta.model.objects.all()`. При вызове имеем в качестве аргумента `self` вызов экземпляра из БД: `ENTRY_TYPES_DICT = get_etypes(EntryType.objects.get(pk=1))` и снова возвращаемся к первоначальному исключению -  **NameError: name 'EntryType' is not defined**

Comment: Добавил полный `Traceback` при оригинальном варианте кода.